# How can you add an image to a Core Plot CPTBarPlot layer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

Is it possible to add a UIImageView to a CPTBarPlot layer (from the Core Plot framework)? I have tried the following, but it only creates the image in the corner of the graph and I want it to be on the bar:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wrong.png"];          
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];
        UIImageView *incorrect = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(plot.bounds.origin.x,plot.bounds.origin.y,14,14)];
        [incorrect setImage:image];
        [plot addSublayer:incorrect.layer];

        [image release];
        [incorrect release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this by creating a CPTFill with the image, and using the delegate/data source of the bar plot to return the fill for the bar.

If you don't want the image actually in the bar, but next to or on top of it, best to create a CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation, and attach that to the plot area.